# Cassandra process grows in ram usage and is never freed

Tags: cassandra, pyspark, datastax-enterprise

Using the latest DSE 6.0.1.

All 7 nodes have 64G of ram and are configured to use a MAX of 32G. When we run `top` the cassandra process takes roughly 61% of RAM.

We start pyspark shell and run simple count query against cassandra tables.

After few seconds we get a lot of:

> WARN  2018-07-19 10:52:47,983
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0
>   (TID 1, 10.5.7.56, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited
>   caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with code 1
>   WARN  2018-07-19 10:52:47,984
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 69.0 in stage 0.0
>   (TID 78, 10.5.7.56, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3
>   exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 1 WARN  2018-07-19 10:52:47,984
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 82.0 in stage 0.0
>   (TID 99, 10.5.7.56, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3
>   exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 1 WARN  2018-07-19 10:52:47,984
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 36.0 in stage 0.0
>   (TID 36, 10.5.7.56, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3
>   exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 1 WARN  2018-07-19 10:52:47,984
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 59.0 in stage 0.0
>   (TID 57, 10.5.7.56, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3
>   exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 1 WARN  2018-07-19 10:52:47,985
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 22.0 in stage 0.0
>   (TID 15, 10.5.7.56, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3
>   exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 1 [Stage
>   0:===================================================>(1406 + 19) /
>   1425]ERROR 2018-07-19 10:53:18,165
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 7 on
>   10.5.7.56: Command exited with code 137 WARN  2018-07-19 10:53:18,166 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 908.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 932, 10.5.7.56, executor 7): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 137 WARN  2018-07-19 10:53:18,166
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1377.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 1240, 10.5.7.56, executor 7): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 137 WARN  2018-07-19 10:53:18,167
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1378.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 1243, 10.5.7.56, executor 7): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 137 WARN  2018-07-19 10:53:18,167
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 940.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 965, 10.5.7.56, executor 7): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 137 WARN  2018-07-19 10:53:18,167
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 864.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 911, 10.5.7.56, executor 7): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with
>   code 137

at that point pyspark job fails and all of cassandra processes on all nodes go up in ram consumption to about 85% and NEVER go back down, even after exiting from pyspark shell.

The only way to free up the ram is to restart each process.

UPDATE:

nodetool status output:

```
Datacenter: Cassandra
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.5.7.53  2.1 TiB    32           ?       8c441d54-c5ae-42c0-819a-6d6b597c9903  rack1
UN  10.5.7.52  1.79 TiB   32           ?       efdc8d20-72a2-4b99-a88c-4a8c5ed6be93  rack1
UN  10.5.7.55  1.5 TiB    32           ?       3d72fb6b-a45f-46af-abdd-b8b7b13873cf  rack1
UN  10.5.7.54  2.02 TiB   32           ?       886849ff-90ac-4ed0-940e-92d92a54cc49  rack1
UN  10.5.7.51  1.99 TiB   32           ?       7834b960-f074-4139-82de-9444320130d1  rack1
UN  10.5.7.57  1.72 TiB   32           ?       bc195dbd-4449-423b-8527-5cf9669c1bd3  rack1
UN  10.5.7.56  1.89 TiB   32           ?       51e2ad43-fb44-4729-a55f-437ce5b1f505  rack1
```

Comment: Can you provide add the following to the ticket: `nodetool status` output, Table schema you're using here, the query you are pushing in via pyspark. Also its likely that you have issues in the cluster itself on the nodes, do you see any WARN, ERROR, in your `var/log/cassandra/system.log` ?

Comment: The errors are the same - OutOfMemory ... how can it be out of memory if my commuted ram is set to 12GB out of 64GB?
I'm reading a parquet file and writing back to csv, nothing intense. What I see is Linux OOM kills the process ... I just don't understand why DSE process starts with 25% Ram used to over 95% (looking at the `top` command output)

Comment: Ok so the architecture in DSE6.0 is different. Disk cache is not used from the OS for a start. There is much more use of off heap memory. Try looking at setting your `file_cache_size_in_mb` lower in the `cassandra.yaml` for a start and as you are running an analytics workload then also try reducing `tpc_cores` also. General recommendation is num physical CPU cores - 1